# get an html page title of pages other than itself

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to look at the title of a html page other than itself? (like google)

`document.title` Wont work as it only works for the page your on.

I want to automatically make links tags with a good name.

Comment: You want to know the names of people living nearby? go to them one by one and ask them (ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this php file get_external_content.php:

```
  <?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$url = $_REQUEST["url"];
$html = file_get_contents_curl($url);

preg_match('/<title>(.+)<\/title>/',$html,$matches);
$title = $matches[1];

echo  json_encode(array("url" => $url, "title" => $title));
```

then in javascript:

```
function getTitle(externalUrl){
  var proxyurl = "http://localhost/get_external_content.php?url=" + externalUrl;
  $.ajax({
    url: proxyurl,
    async: true,
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    },   
    error: function(e) {
      alert("error! " + e);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: all i get is "$ is not defined" i am using xmapp if that helps

Comment: You have to include jQuery library for my example to work the $ will be defined then.